# d3js svg diagram editor stack elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, diagram

I am currently developing a diagram editor in SVG. (Like in Papyrus just with javascript).

So far I can create nodes and resize them and drag them.

But now I got a problem (Child is outside the parent):

[image: Child is outside the parent]

So to explain this picture. If i click the background(red) the parent spawns(green). Now if I click the parent the child spawns(yellow) but it should be not displayed outside the parent. Maybe I want to add there scroll bars so I can scroll inside the parent to see the full child but in the first place, it should not be displayed outside the parent.

My svg structure looks like this:

```
<div id="diagram_container">   
     <svg width="5000" height="5000">
        <g ("rootg")>
            <g ("innerg")>
                <rect id="parent" x="100" y="100" width="200" height="200"></rect>
                <rect id="child" x="150" y="150" width="100" height="100"></rect>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

Maybe I got already a problem in the structure or it's just a missing property.

Can somebody tell me the proper way to do that?

Comment: I think this is way too broad. SVG has no features at all that would support you here - it's just a description of the graphics and you are describing the behavior. This must all be done in your JS logic which you did not post. I don't see how d3js is involved in your sample, but if third party libraries are an option, the behavior you are looking for is the default in more advanced graph drawing libraries, e.g. in [yFiles for HTML](https://www.yworks.com/yfileshtml)

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply! and thanks for the link to yFiles that gave a good inspiration :)